# Как сохранить данные из QTableWidget в .xls?

Tags: python, pyqt5, xls

ситуация такая: программа на python 3 создает и заполняет таблицу qtablewidget данными, в ней есть текст и картинки. Хочу все это дело импортировать в exel, т.е. в .xls файлик. Для работы с xls использовал xlrd и xlwt.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как сохранить картинки, с импортом текста проблем нет. И второй вопрос, как реализовать процесс сохранения по типу "сохранить как", т.е. чтобы я мог выбрать путь сохранения .xls файла?

Функция сохранения данных с таблицы в xls имеет такой вид:

```
def get_data(self):
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook('D:\\12345.xls',formatting_info=True)
    sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    ws = wb.add_sheet('111')
    rows = self.table.rowCount()
    cols = self.table.columnCount()
    data = []
    for row in range(rows):
        tmp = []
        for col in range(cols):
            try:
                tmp.append(self.table.item(row,col).text())
            except:
                tmp.append('No data')
        data.append(tmp)
    i=0
    for n in data:
        ws.write(i,0,n[0])
        ws.write(i,1,n[1])
        ws.write(i,2,n[2])
        ws.write(i,3,n[3])
        ws.write(i,4,n[4])
        ws.write(i,5,n[5])
        ws.write(i,6,n[6])
        ws.write(i,7,n[7])
        i=i+1
    wb.save('D:\\12345_rec.xls')
```

Comment: Наверное, не импортировать, а экспортировать?

Comment: ну это смотря с какой стороны смотреть.. Если от таблицы exel, то я в нее импортирую данные с qtablewidget. =)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на первый вопрос ([отсюда](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images.html)):

```
# Вставка изображения
worksheet.write('A2', 'Insert an image in a cell:')
worksheet.insert_image('B2', 'python.png')
```

Второй. Воспользоваться `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName`:

```
fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save excel-file", "", "Excel Files (*.xls)")
if fileName:
    ...
    wb.save(fileName)
```

Comment: А с помощью модулей xlrd и xlwt - это можно реализовать?

Comment: "сохранить как" работает, спасибо!

Comment: а также по первому вопросу, я не знаю как с qtable вытянуть изображение, это также необходимо перед тем как записывать в xls.

Comment: @AndreyShulgin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103878/insert-image-using-xlwt-python-odoo

Comment: @AndreyShulgin вот еще https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172944/insert-an-image-base-64-on-excel-using-xlwt

Comment: @AndreyShulgin как вытянуть из qtable изображение это уже другой вопрос

Comment: в моей ситуации - это все один вопрос) Ок, буду дальше разбираться... А вам спасибо за помощь!